# Laravel: Config::get() / config() muestra el contenido completo de .env

Tags: laravel

Estoy haciendo pruebas con Laravel Mail y cuando mando el email me sale el contenido completo del archivo `.env`

(aquí recortado)
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo en concreto es: `views/vendor/mail/html/message.blade.php`

```
@component('mail::layout')
    {{-- Header --}}
    @slot('header')
        @component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
            {{ config('app.name') }}{{-- Problema --}}
        @endcomponent
    @endslot
...
```

El `['url' => config('app.url')]` lo muestra bien.
El problema es el segundo `{{ config('app.name') }}` y en el footer hay otro igual y también muestra todo el contenido del `.env`.

Si pongo un `string`, todo va bien.

Lo que he probado:

- Limpiar el cache (todo)
- Cambiando a `debug=false` y en producción

Comment: Bastante curioso, hice una prueba en una instalación limpia de Laravel 5.7 y me funcionó sin que me aparecieran dichos datos

Comment: @Shaz - Brutal esto... me he vuelto loco!! No me he acordado que en algún momento he metido el fichero `environment.php` (ver respuesta)... Gracias de todas formas por tu tiempo!

Answer (score 1):

Tenía un sistema de deployment con distintos `.env` para `.local.env`, `.staging.env` y `.production.env`. (Servidor NGINX)

Luego tenía un fichero `environment.php`.

Se implementaba en `bootstrap/app.php` - `require __DIR__.'/environment.php';`:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment( function() {

  $environmentPath = __DIR__.'/../.env';
  $setEnv          = trim( file_get_contents( $environmentPath ) );

  if ( file_exists( $environmentPath ) ) {

    putenv( "$setEnv" );

    if ( getenv( 'APP_ENV' ) && file_exists( __DIR__.'/../.'.getenv( 'APP_ENV' ).'.env' ) ) {

      $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv( __DIR__.'/../', '.'.getenv( 'APP_ENV' ).'.env' );
      $dotenv->load();
    }
  }
} );
```

Entonces, he detectado posibles problemas, uno de ellos era que no estaba habilitado `getenv()` y para eso había que habilitar lo siguiente:

En `php.ini`: Cambiar `variables_order = "GPCS"` a `variables_order = "EGPCS"`

En `php-fpm` descomentar la linea `clear_env = no`:

```
; Clear environment in FPM workers
; Prevents arbitrary environment variables from reaching FPM worker processes
; by clearing the environment in workers before env vars specified in this
; pool configuration are added.
; Setting to "no" will make all environment variables available to PHP code
; via getenv(), $_ENV and $_SERVER.
; Default Value: yes
clear_env = no
```

Y aún así, no se ha solucionado nada.

El problema está(*ba*) que no puede leer el `getenv( 'APP_ENV' ) //=> false`.

Tras casi 1 día de intentar de arreglarlo fue la única solución de eliminar el archivo `environment.php` y ahora si funciona todo como debe...

Dejo la respuesta tal cual, hasta que alguien me ilumine y me pueda decir **CUAL** es/era el problema real.